# respond with 404 error from asp.net page codebehind

Tags: asp.net

I have a scenario in which I'm [serving a file](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/76293.aspx) from codebehind.

which file, depends on request. in some cases there will be no file to serve and I want to return 404 to the browser.

how can I do that from codebehind? is this the correct course of action to show user there's no file available?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use the [Response.StatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode.aspx) property to return a 404:

```
Page.Response.StatusCode = 404
```

As for the question of whether it's the "correct thing to do" I'd say it depends how the Page is going to be accessed.  If you're going to access it programmatically then yes I'd go with the 404.  If however it is going to be a user facing system, then I'd go with a custom page of some sort.  Programs like codes and humans like more understandable things :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
throw new HttpException(404, "File not found");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be more inclined to redirect them to a custom error page that clearly indicates that the file cannot be found, in the style of the rest of your web application.

You can specify how to handle certain errors in web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```