# How to use local variable of a function in different page, Vs 2005, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to use a local variable of a function of a control in a different page in Asp.net.

I am new, please help me out!

Thanks!

Comment: In a code behind page, I want to use a local variable that is declared in a function of a different class in a different page. How is that possible?
Ex: Istrial is a variable declared and used in PromoCode() in UCPaymentControl page. I want to use it in MerchantProfilePages page. How is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this because:

1. Local variables are not accessible outside of the method they are declared in (did you mean fields?)
2. Pages from one request do not even exist when you're on a new page during the subsequent request.  It's stateless.

Consider using cookies/viewstate/query strings/etc.

Comment: Ok i understand! Now can you pls tel me if there is a way to stop loading a page depending on a bool value. I mean, if istrial is false, i want to stop a page from loading all the times. is that possible??

Comment: `If isTrial Then Response.Redirect("some other page")`

Comment: Its not the page that should be redirected or not. That page should not be available at all times. Is that something foolish to ask??

Comment: When the user requests a page you have to send them something you can't just stop, you should probably send them some kind of error page.

Comment: You could return an error code of 404, Page Not Found.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095030/respond-with-404-error-from-asp-net-page-codebehind